# relauch cordova app from external browser

Tags: android, cordova, browser, apache-cordova

I have developed a cordova android app, do to some security issues I should open a specific link in external browser using

```
window.open(url , '_system');
```

I want to have a button in that page which can lead the user to the app (doesn't matter the last visited page or just relaunch the app again).

I tested

```
<a href="javascript:self.close()">back to app</a>
```

this one worked well but there is a problem that if in your Google Chrome you have pre opened tabs after pressing this button, the current tab would close but other tab would show up.

is ther any way to redirect the user to app or start the app?

tnx